# Is there any Impact Of AMI Creation On Network Bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've multiple ec2 instances in my AWS VPC some of which run web servers while a few run production databases. There's a good amount of traffic during daytime. I've a m4.large ec2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with 300GB data in one of its attached 1000GB EBS volumes. This instance is for testing purposes and not part of the production environment. Would there be any impact of creating AMI for this instance, say during the day time, in terms of the overall network bandwidth utilisation of the VPC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no impact to your VPC or any of your network infrastructure from creating an AMI.

Creating an AMI means implicitly creating snapshots of all the EBS volumes attached to the instance (as many of them as you select) but snapshots are created by the EBS service, which has direct access to the volumes on a network that is entirely separate from your VPC.  The instance itself, and your VPC as a whole, have no role in AMI creation.

If you resume use of the instance before AMI creation is complete (which is safe to do, once the snapshots are all in progress), then you might see *minor* impairment of *that same machine's* disk performance, but even this is unlikely unless you create more than one AMI of the machine at the same time, by starting one before the previous one has finished (which would be pretty unusual).  Simultaneous actions like this would increase the amount of traffic the volume itself needs to handle in order to provide snapshot contents to the EBS snapshot service, but even this should not be a factor if you are only creating one at a time... and in any event the scope would be limited to that instance only.

Comment: Thanks Michael. That was very detailed and insightful.